# Creating variations does not add data to wp_term_relationships

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

after creating variations the wp_term_relationships table is not getting updated with variation id / object_id and attribute term id / term_taxonomy_id
Because of this, I cannot perform tax_query on product_variation.

My tax_query example:

```
$query_args = array(
‘post_type’ => ‘product_variation’,
‘post_status’ => ‘publish’,
‘posts_per_page’ => $attributes[‘limit’],
‘tax_query’ => array(

array(
‘taxonomy’ => ‘pa_purchase-as’,
‘field’ => ‘slug’,
‘terms’ => array(‘mirror’),
),

)
);
```

Note:
however, the attributes are getting saved perfectly for variations and I can get them via get_attributes(). It must be saving attributes as JSON in wp_post_meta.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Woocommerce doesn't store the variations attributes in term_relationships table it stores the attribute value in meta key "attribute_your_att_slug".

In my case, the value is stored as meta key "attribute_pa_purchase-as".

So, if you want to get the variations based on attributes you can use meta query instead of tax_query to get results as I've used in the following example:

```
$query_args = array(
‘post_type’ => ‘product_variation’,
‘post_status’ => ‘publish’,
‘posts_per_page’ => $attributes[‘limit’],

'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'attribute_'.trim($attributes['attribute']),
                'value' => $terms,
                'compare' => 'IN',
            )
)

);
```

Hope that helps someone. :)